# Where can I download old versions of Appcelerator Studio?

Tags: appcelerator

Appcelerator Studio version 4.6 just doesn't work for me. Where can I get the old versions - 4.5, 4.0, whatever - to download and run?

4.6 doesn't let me "revert" to older versions, because it is just completely broken and not a working product.

The reason I want to do this is simply because I cannot get it to recognise my Nexus 6P device.

If I delete the config.json file in users/me/.titanium/ then the *first* time it loads it will find the Nexus 6P, and then after trying to install to it it will fail with "invalid device" and then completely forget it was ever connected to the Nexus 6P.

Comment: "Doesn't work for me" is very broad. Please specify what doesn't work

Comment: Let me know what doesn't work in Appcelerator Studio 4.6, I'm happy to help you.

Comment: I don't say what works and what doesn't, but we have a legacy app that was built with some specific version of appcelerator studio. We have to maintain it and we have an official requirement that we use that old version. OTOH it is not quite obvious from the installation instructions where can I take the old version. This is why I think that some essential part of this question is useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download all the Appcelerator SDK versions here: http://builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#master

But instead of downgrade your version, have you tried to update it?
There is also nightly builds at that page.

If you need to downgrade the Appcelerator Studio, at this link you have a list of the Titanium Studio versions:
https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Reverting+to+a+Previous+Version#RevertingtoaPreviousVersion-PreviouslyReleasedTitaniumStudioVersions

Instead of:

```
http://titanium-studio.s3.amazonaws.com/3.4.0/Titanium_Studio.dmg
```

You change the version number to the requested version and the file name to Appcelerator_Studio

```
http://titanium-studio.s3.amazonaws.com/4.5.0/Appcelerator_Studio.dmg
```

Comment: I think it is about Studio, not the SDK's

Comment: have you tried a full reinstall? or appc setup?

Comment: `appc setup` doesn't work if you don't use `appc`/free version ;)

Comment: Thanks - the last link (although i replaced the .dmg with a .exe) worked the charm